# Defining Foreign Key in Unary Relationship

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I have the table assignment which should have two FK - ManagerID & ManagerProjID

```
CREATE TABLE Assignment
    (
        RescID NUMBER (8) NOT NULL ,
        RProjID NUMBER (4) NOT NULL ,
        AssignRole VARCHAR2(100) ,
        ManagerID NUMBER (8) ,
        ManagerProjID NUMBER (4),
        CONSTRAINT Assignment_PK PRIMARY KEY ( RescID, RProjID)


    )
;
```

When I try running the command

```
ALTER TABLE Assignment
    ADD CONSTRAINT Assignment_Manager_FK FOREIGN KEY
    ( MANAGERID )
    REFERENCES Assignment
    ( MANAGERID )
;
```

I am getting an error of no matching unique or primary key for this column-list.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not implementing what your question heading states. It is trying to self reference a column `ManagerID`.

You cannot have a `foreign key` reference on a column which is not a `primary key` or a `unique key` as there will be no way of enforcing the uniqueness of the column being referenced. `ManagerProjID` is a non-unique column and hence you cannot create a foriegn key reference on it.

Answer (score 1):

A `Foreign key` cannot reference to itself. It can refer only to a `PrimaryKey`

Answer (score 1):

Add primary key to your table and reference primary key to a foreign key.